# Strange behavior with function Copy.File on virtual VM

Tags: c#

I wrote the following function, which copies file(s) to computers:

```
public void CopyFile()
{
    //data
    _pathcopy = txtb_to.Text;
    _computers = txtb_pc.Lines;
    _copyfiles = txtb_from.Text;

    string fileName = GetFileNameFromLabel(_copyfiles);
    string from = Path.Combine(_copyfiles);
    foreach (var comp in _computers)
    {
        string topath = GetUNCPath(_pathcopy, comp, fileName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(GetUNCPath(_pathcopy, comp));
        try
        {
            File.Copy(from, topath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

        }
    }
}

private string GetFileNameFromLabel(string path)
{
    string fName = Path.GetFileName(path);

    return fName;
}

private string GetUNCPath(string path, string pc)
{
    string ffp = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path + @"\"));
    string uncpath = @"\\" + pc + @"\" + ffp.Replace(":", "$");
    return uncpath;
}

private string GetUNCPath(string path, string pc, string fln)
{
    string ffp = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path + @"\" + fln));
    string uncpath = @"\\" + pc + @"\" + ffp.Replace(":", "$");
    return uncpath;
}
```

It works if I run the program on a real computer. But if I run it in a VM, I get the following error:

> "The given path's format is not supported."

I compare strings in debugger, but they are equal.

```
    System.NotSupportedException
      HResult=0x80131515
      Message=The given path's format is not supported.
      Source=mscorlib
      StackTrace:
       at         

 System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at CopyInstall.Form1.CopyFile() in \\dc1\temp\CopyInstall\CopyInstall\Form1.cs:line 47
   at CopyInstall.Form1.bt_Copy_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \\dc1\temp\CopyInstall\CopyInstall\Form1.cs:line 28
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at CopyInstall.Program.Main() in \\dc1\temp\CopyInstall\CopyInstall\Program.cs:line 19
```

I repeat, file exist, path correct. I have admin rights.

Comment: That means you used the wrong path. There's nothing special about VMs and .NET.  You didn't post the exception or the string that caused the problem though, so it's impossible to say what's wrong, or even which method failed. Post the *full** exception including the call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Add proper logging to the code and log what went wrong, where, what values were used.

Comment: BTW what's the point of all those replacements and adding `$` ? You can't access adminstrative shares like C$, D$ unless you *are* an administrator.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but what was the *intention* behind the line `string from = Path.Combine(_copyfiles);`?

Comment: I am admin on all PCs.

Comment: What does  a failing path look like?  What happens if you take that path and paste it into the explorer address bar/run dialog?

Comment: Is the user on the VM - whichever one is running your app - ALSO admin on those shares?

Comment: You also might look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yes, Vm user enterprise admin user.

Answer (score 1):

It was strange bug. I rebooted all VM and bug is gone

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove last "\" from the destination location.

```
private string GetUNCPath(string path, string pc)
{
    string ffp = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path);  // + @"\"));
    string uncpath = @"\\" + pc + @"\" + ffp.Replace(":", "$");
    return uncpath;
}
```

If this doesn't work, then you have permission issues. Maybe from VM you have no permission to write on remote folder.

Comment: It didn't help. If i can open UNC path and write/del/edit/copy folder/file, it doesn't mean that i have rights?

Comment: But this code is work Directory.CreateDirectory(GetUNCPath(_pathcopy, comp)); Folder has created.

Comment: Can you show what you get in "from" and "topath" in File.Copy(from, topath);

Comment: Do you "Run As Administrator" your program?

Comment: from "D:\\shara\\TeamViewer_Setup.exe" string
  topath "\\\\WS7-TEST\\c$\\temp\\TeamViewer_Setup.exe" string
Yes. I am enterprise admin) run as admin, not helped, but the folder is created.